# What frameworks are ported to perl?

Tags: perl

Are there any frameworks that were developed in another language and then ported to Perl? For example, [Dotiac](http://www.dotiac.com/cgi-bin/index.pl) is a port of [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) templates and Django is a Python framework.

Are there any others?

Comment: thanx. Need learn how to post correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a web framework, but near: [Plucene](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plucene) is a Perl port of the Lucene search engine.

Comment: [KinoSearch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?KinoSearch), now called [Lucy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lucy) and living in the Apache foundation, is as well and it’s a good enough port that Lucene is trying to backport some of the new code.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/web_frameworks contains a list of perl frameworks.  You could check them and report back.

Comment: thanx. Anyway at the link for example does not shown the mentioned Dotiac, what is a perl port of Djago templates. I hope someone tell me some like Dotiac.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if *ported* is the right word, but [Dancer was inspired by Sinatra](http://perldancer.org/about).